# Error (RoR Tutorial) -dropdown not firing w/bootstrap- session destroy path incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, railstutorial.org

Error in Rails Tutorial (Hartl) v3.2

I'm on chapter 8 and all tests pass correctly prior to the exercises. Except two issues (I think they're related).

The dropdown-menu is not firing with bootstrap as the session destroy path appears to be incorrect. I'm also attempting to use the form_tag in place of the form_for tag and I keep getting the following error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the new_html.erb under app/views/sessions:

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>

      <%= label_tag :email %>
      <%= text_field_tag :email %>

      <%= label_tag :password %>
      <%= password_field_tag :password %>

      <%= submit_tag "Sign in", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Finally, here's the rake routes output:

```
      users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
            POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
   sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       sessions#create
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   sessions#new
    session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   sessions#destroy
     signup        /signup(.:format)         users#new
     signin        /signin(.:format)         sessions#new
    signout DELETE /signout(.:format)        sessions#destroy
       help        /help(.:format)           static_pages#help
      about        /about(.:format)          static_pages#about
    contact        /contact(.:format)        static_pages#contact
       root        /                         static_pages#home
```

Any help would be great.

Edit:

cbright had it. I had to modify the sessions_controller. The following two lines work as intended.

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The session symbol used with form_for is no longer being used, so replace params[:session][:email] and params[:session][:password] with params[:email] params[:password].

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Updated original question with the correct code.